# remove prevAll : first item with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side

What i`m doing wrong in my code:

```
  $.each($("input[value='"+id+"']"), function(index, value) {
            alert($(this).val());
            $("input[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").prevAll('.t-item:first').remove();
        });
```

Html schema:

[image: Html Schema]

p.s im doing 'each' since i have the same html on other place on my page so i want to remove from both places

In this html example, my id is 249 or 293

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do?  prevAll will look for previous siblings but you are passing in an ancestor.. If you could explain what you are doing and what's supposed to happen it would be a lot easier to help

Comment: I want to remove whole <li> so if my value of this example is 293, i want to remove <li class='t-item t-last'> * </li>

Comment: Why not just do `$(this).closest('li.t-item').remove()`?

Comment: what you really want to remove is not clear. is it <li> or <span>s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
  $.each($("input[value='"+id+"']"), function(index, value) {
            alert($(this).val());
            $(this).closest('.t-item').remove();
        });
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

`Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.`

Comment: work! But it should work as i write it..i dont know why, it so logical, get all previews with 'selector:first'... nvm, problem solved

Answer (score 3):

From the markup it looks like you're trying to remove the `<li class="t-item">` ancestor of the input, in that case use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
    $.each($("input[value='"+id+"']"), function(index, value) {
        alert($(this).val());
        $(this).closest('.t-item').remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
$(this).closest('.t-item').remove();
```

instead of: `$("input[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").prevAll('.t-item:first').remove();`

http://api.jquery.com/closest

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[value="+id+"]").closest('.t-item').remove();
```